# Faster way to pick pairs of integer coordinates from a "region"

Tags: performance-tuning, filtering, findinstance

I am trying to find a faster way to do this than what I have put together or by looping through a bunch of points.

I want to select all pairs of integer points ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) such that:

1. Point (x1,y1) is at a specified distance r1 from center point (xc,yc).
2. Point (x2,y2) is farther away from the center point than the point (x1,y1) is.
3. Points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are separated by a specified distance r2.
4. These points will be referring to 512X512 images, so each x and y value is limited to be between 1 and 512. Also because of this, I am having distances r1 and r2 only be integers, and I round any distances calculated between two points to the nearest integer.

Conceptually, for each point (x1, y1) that is a distance r1 from the center point, I am selecting all points that are a distance r2 from (x1, y1) and farther away from the center point. In the end, I want a list of pairs of points ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)). Here is my function:

```
points[r1_, r2_] :=
 Select[{x1, y1, x2, y2} /.
   FindInstance[
    1 <= x1 <= 512 &&
     1 <= y1 <= 512 &&
     1 <= x2 <= 512 &&
     1 <= y2 <= 512 &&
     Round[Sqrt[(x1 - xc)^2 + (y1 - yc)^2]] == r1 &&
     r1 <= Round[Sqrt[(x2 - xc)^2 + (y2 - yc)^2]] <= (r1 + r2),
    {x1, y1, x2, y2}, Integers, 512^2],
  Round[Sqrt[(#[[1]] - #[[3]])^2 + (#[[2]] - #[[4]])^2]] == r2 &]
```

I put condition 3 in the Select function rather than in the FindInstance function because the FindInstance function couldn't handle it. 512^2 maximum number of instances is a lot larger than I need, but it seems like having that number be too large doesn't hurt anything.

My code works, it is just very slow. The smallest r1 value I am using is 197, and r2 starts at 0 (r1 and r2 are limited to integers as well). My center point for now is at (229,256). I am sure there is an easier way to do this that is also faster. Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to Michael E2 and Henrik Schumacher for helping with a faster solution. Although the below answers were not what I was looking for specifically, I was able to use them to obtain what I was looking for. Here is what I have put together:

```
pointFind[r_, c_] := 
  ArrayPad[(SparseArray@DiskMatrix[r]*
       SparseArray@(1 - DiskMatrix[r - 1, 2*r + 1])) // Transpose, 
    Transpose@{c - r - 1, 512 - c - r}]["NonzeroPositions"];

points[r1_, r2_, 
   c_] := ({#, 
       pointFind[r2, #]} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} /; 
        Round[Norm[{x, y} - c]] < r1 -> Nothing) & /@ 
   pointFind[r1, c];
```

Here is an example of the result:

```
test = points[20, 10, {100, 100}];
Show[
 ListPlot[test[[;; , 1]],
  PlotRange -> {{65, 125}, {65, 125}},
  PlotStyle -> Black],
 ListPlot[test[[1, 2]],
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 Graphics[{Red, Point[test[[1, 1]]]}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I have plotted all points a rounded distance r1 (20) from the center, and then I picked one such point and show all of the points a distance r2 (10) from the first point that are farther from the center.

[image]

This works much much faster than what I had before. Thanks for everything!

Comment: What do you mean by "Select all pairs of points" - what will be returned by the function `points`?  A `Region` or a pair of points randomly selected to fit the criteria?

Comment: Right now it returns a list of lists {x1,y1,x2,y2} that meet the criteria.

Comment: The points are not being randomly selected. Given an r1 and r2, find ALL pairs ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: do you really mean to find points at an *exact integer* distance `r1`?  That changes the problem a good bit if you want exact vs allowing some tolerance.

Comment: I guess technically I am allowing ranges of r-.5 and r+.5 for an integer r. That is why I say in my post that any distance I am measuring I round to the nearest integer. I just want to keep everything in terms of integers since I am dealing with pixels in an image. I am putting everything in terms of "to the nearest pixel". I am aware that not all distances will be exact integers, which is why I am rounding these distances to the nearest integer. The rounding is what supplies the tolerance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Update 2: Used `Nearest` to compute final points `pts`. Another significant speed up.]*

The OP's "distance" seems a bit odd and does not obey the triangle inequality. It leads to some odd points.  But maybe that's what is being explored.  For `r1 = 220, r2 = 130` it takes <s>27 sec.</s> <s>9 sec.</s> 2.2 sec. Some of the black (x1,y1) points have no neighbor closer than `Sqrt[2]` which leads to occasional holes in the red (x2,y2) points.

A not very interesting brute-force method. *[Update: I was working out a faster way, and during that time Henrik Schumacher also had the idea of using `DiskMatrix`. Multiplying the sparse arrays is slightly faster than subtracting the arrays. It's much faster than my original.]*

*[Update 3: In response to a comment asking for the pairs, I included two `Association` structures, `p1$p2` to map `{x1, y1}` to the associated points `{x2, y2}`, and the inverse relation `p2$p1`.]*

```
points2[{r1_, r2_}, c_] := 
  ArrayPad[(SparseArray@DiskMatrix[r2] *
       (SparseArray[1 - DiskMatrix[r1 - 1, 2 r2 + 1]])) // Transpose, 
    Transpose@{c - r2 - 1, 512 - c - r2}]["NonzeroPositions"];

Module[{r1 = 20, r2 = 10, c = {100, 100}, nf, p2$for$p1},
   pts1 = points2[{r1, r1}, c];
   pts2 = points2[{r1 + 1, r1 + r2}, c];
   nf = Nearest[pts1];
   p2$for$p1 = MapThread[     (* gets the points {x2, y2} for each point {x1, y1} *)
     Complement, {nf[pts2, {All, r2 + 1/2}], nf[pts2, {All, r2 - 1/2}]}];

   pts = Pick[pts2, Length /@ p2$for$p1 // Unitize, 1];  (* red points below *)
   p2$p1 = AssociationThread[pts2 -> p2$for$p1];         (* {x2, y2} -> {x1, y1} *)
   p1$p2 = Merge[Join]@ KeyValueMap[                     (* {x1, y1} -> {x2, y2} *)
      Function[{p2, p1}, AssociationThread[p1, \[FormalP]] /. \[FormalP] -> p2], 
      p2$p1];
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.030094, Null} -- was {0.007771, Null} for just pts *)

Graphics[With[{r1 = 20, r2 = 10},
  {
   Circle[{100, 100}, r1 - 1/2], Circle[{100, 100}, r1 + 1/2],
   Point@pts1,
   Red, Circle[{100, 100}, r1 + r2 + 1/2],
   Point[pts]
   }
  ], GridLines -> {Range@512, Range@512}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example use of the associations:

```
pts2[[138]]              (* pick a point {x2, y2} *)
(*  {75, 105}  *)

mypts2 = {75, 105};
mypts1 = p2$p1[mypts2]   (* gets the points {x2, y2} corresponding to {75, 105} *) 
Round[Norm[# - {100, 100}]] & /@ mypts  (* check distance *)
(*
{{80, 96}, {83, 111}}
{20, 20}
*)

p1$p2[First@mypts]       (* gets points {x2, y2} associated to {80, 96} *)
(*
{{70, 95}, {70, 96}, {70, 97}, {70, 98}, {70, 99}, {71, 91}, {71, 92}, {71, 100},
 {71, 101}, {72, 90}, {72, 102}, {73, 89}, {73, 103}, {74, 88}, {74, 104}, {75, 87},
 {75, 105}, {76, 87}, {76, 105}, {77, 86}, {77, 106}, {78, 86}, {78, 106}, {79, 86},
 {79, 106}, {80, 86}, {80, 106}, {81, 86}, {82, 86}, {83, 86}, {84, 87}}
*)

Norm[N[First@mypts - #]] & /@ p1$p2[First@mypts] // Round (* check distances *)
(*
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}
*)
```

Comment: Hey Michael, something is odd here. When I run your code the image produced is quite different from the one I see here and I don't know how to interpret it...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, Henrik. I forgot to update the definition of `points2[]`.

Comment: The speed looks very nice, and the output image looks like what I was imagining when visualizing all such pairs! I am going to try to unpack this right now to understand it more, but is there a way to modify this to keep the pairs together? I need the pairs of points ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) kept together. Obviously, there will be multiple pairs corresponding to the same (x1,y1), but I need to keep them all together. I will go through it myself to see if I can do it, but if you realize it faster then I can go with that.

Comment: @AaronStevens Please see the update. I wasn't sure in what form (data structure) you wanted the pairs.  If you just want the straight pairs, I think this works: `Table[ArrayPad[List /@ Complement[nf[p, {All, r2 + 1/2}], nf[p, {All, r2 - 1/2}]], {{0}, {1, 0}}, {{p}}], {p, pts2}]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `DiskMatrix` is of interest for you. This is not a complete answer, but I try to show how you might apply `DiskMatrix` to your problem. For example, the set of all points `{x1,y1}` as specified above can be obtained with the following function:

```
digitalCirclePoints[xc_, yc_, a_, b_, r_] := 
 Module[{xlist, ylist, ipos, pat},
  {xlist, ylist} = Transpose[SparseArray[
      Subtract[
       DiskMatrix[r, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}],
       DiskMatrix[r - 1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}]
       ]]["NonzeroPositions"]
    ];
  xlist = Clip[xlist + xc - (r + 1), {1, a}, {0, 0}];
  ylist = Clip[ylist + yc - (r + 1), {1, b}, {0, 0}];
  ipos = Flatten[Position[Positive[xlist ylist], True, 1]];
  pat = Transpose[{xlist[[ipos]], ylist[[ipos]]}]
  ]
```

Here are some usage examples:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
a = 64;
b = 48;
g = GraphicsGrid@Table[
   xc = RandomInteger[{1, a}];
   yc = RandomInteger[{1, b}];
   r1 = RandomInteger[{1, Mean[{a, b}]}];
   ArrayPlot[
    Transpose@
     SparseArray[digitalCirclePoints[xc, yc, a, b, r1] -> 1, {a, b}]],
   {3}, {3}]
```

[image]

Analogously, you can find the points `{x2,y2}` belonging to each `{x1,y1}` in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

```
centerpt = {5, 9};
r1 = 3;
r2 = 1;
fullpairs = {};
Table[
  firstpt = RandomPoint[Circle[centerpt, r1]];
  secondpt = RandomPoint[Circle[firstpt, r2]];
  If[EuclideanDistance[centerpt, secondpt] > 
     EuclideanDistance[centerpt, firstpt], 
   AppendTo[fullpairs, {firstpt, secondpt}]],
  {10}];
fullpairs
```

5000 points takes about seven seconds.

Comment: he wants integer pair i think. it is written in the title

Comment: There is no guarantee that integer-coordinate points will obey the stated distance requirements as trivially demonstrated if $r2 = .5$.

Comment: maybe he wants only those integer pairs that verify the relation at different distance r1 and r2

Comment: `r2` must be a integer, at least it clearly must be in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure this is completely right tho

```
pc = {229, 256};
r1 = 197;
r2 = 2;
v = {x, y};
lista = Select[{x, y} /. 
    Solve[EuclideanDistance[v, pc] == r1, v, Integers], 
   1 < #[[1]] < 512 && 1 < #[[2]] < 512 &];

Partition[
 Flatten[Table[
   Select[{x, y} /. 
     Solve[EuclideanDistance[v, lista[[k]]] == r2, v, Integers], 
    EuclideanDistance[pc, #] > 
      EuclideanDistance[pc, lista[[k]]] &], {k, 1, Length[lista]}]],
  2]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to count backwards...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  what do you mean?  I did not get that.

Comment: Just based on [the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Alucard_(character))

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to do this using region tools:

```
cp = {0, 0}
r1 = 10
r2 = 3
tol = .5
annulus[cp_, ri_, ro_] := 
 RegionDifference[Disk[cp, ro], Disk[cp, ri]]
p1 = {x, y} /.   FindInstance[
     Element[{x, y}, annulus[cp, r1 - tol, r1 + tol]], {x, y}, 
     Integers, 100];
result = {#, {x, y}} /. First@FindInstance[Element[{x, y},
        RegionIntersection[
         annulus[#, r2 - tol, r2 + tol],
         annulus[cp, Norm[#], Norm[#] + r2 + 2 tol]]], {x, y}, 
       Integers] & /@ p1;

Graphics[{Arrow /@ result, {Dashed, Circle[cp, r1]}}]
```

[image]

Edit..just noticed you want *all* such pairs. I dont think we can guarantee finding all this way but we can ask `FindInstance` to look for lots..

```
p1 = {x, y} /.  FindInstance[
     Element[{x, y}, annulus[cp, r1 - tol, r1 + tol]], {x, y}, 
     Integers, 
    Ceiling@Area@annulus[{0, 0}, r1 - tol, r1 + tol]];
Length@p1
result = Flatten[
  Function[{pp}, {pp, {x, y} /. #} & /@ 
     FindInstance[Element[{x, y},
         annulus[pp, r2 - tol, r2 + tol]
         ~RegionIntersection~
         annulus[cp, Norm[pp], Norm[pp] + r2 + 2 tol]], {x, y},
        Integers, 
           Ceiling@Area@annulus[{0, 0}, r2 - tol, r2 + tol]] ] /@ p1, 1]
```

this took 20 seconds to find 488 pairs.

[image]

for comparison a brute force version that gives the same result in .1 second.

```
  p1 = Select[Flatten[Table[{i, j} + cp,
       {i, -Ceiling[r1 + 1], Ceiling[r1 + 1]}, 
      {j, -Ceiling[r1 + 1], Ceiling[r1 + 1]}], 1] , 
    r1 - tol < Norm[# - cp] < r1 + tol &];
  result2 = 
   Flatten[Function[{pp}, {pp, #} & /@           
       Select[Flatten[Table[{i, j} + pp, 
          {i, -Ceiling[r2 + 1], Ceiling[r2 + 1]},
          {j, -Ceiling[r2 + 1], Ceiling[r2 + 1]}], 1] , (
          (r2 - tol < Norm[# - pp] < r2 + tol) && (Norm[# - cp] > 
             Norm[pp - cp])) &]] /@ p1, 1];
```

result == result2

> True